# How do I get Xubuntu to stop asking to upgrade to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, 14.10, 15.04

Every time I start my computer I get a notification after the computer gets done checking for updates that says "Software updates are no longer provided for Xubuntu 14.10. To stay secure, you should upgrade to Xubuntu 15.04." I don't want to upgrade I'm happy how my computer is until version 16 LTS comes out. I want to stop getting the notification and get rid of the red triangle with the exclamation mark on my panel. How do I do this?

Comment: If you wanted to wait for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to upgrade, then why didn't you install the current LTS 14.04? As you are currently, you are using an unsupported OS since July 23 and won't get any future security updates.

Answer (score 1):

go to Ubuntu software center, then click edit from top left then software sources. in the updates tab the last option is notify me of a new Ubuntu version. choose Either for long-term supported version, or never.

[image]

Comment: If this helped you marked as the write answer. so not to spend effort of people who will come to read your question .